# Android ButterKnife java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbutterknife/ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, butterknife

I'm getting the follow exception when I try to use Butterknife in my Android project:

```
05-20 14:08:41.221 3296-3296/com.fedorparetsky.parcare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.fedorparetsky.parcare, PID: 3296
                                                                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lbutterknife/ButterKnife;
                                                                         at com.fedorparetsky.parcare.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:31)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "butterknife.ButterKnife" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_eb12f1d5e0839cb98757858d3f14e58a5ea14ee3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-retrofit-2.0.2_317900fd1983688c01450d1ec5906c5a1c05efd1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okio-1.6.0_175d7b922c34081b4b832410087e3085fd821d1c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okhttp-3.2.0_2ceb2f44f424d23ee9f0690f9e73329608c061a6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-mysql-connector-java-5.1.25_355d4321be27ecaa8afcdd4b2c17d478c5f6a2c4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-library-2.4.0_681824be31b9a4f5b9013c1feaea61615d3e4a07-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_6314a7d5980c15845346b6a8b9008223f1faf2b5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.0.0_f9a9db9ee308ac3c11b109ec40e9df56aa8ca9a9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-gson-2.6.1_12043eecea4526f7c51479e9dc708e34fcb0a90e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-converter-gson-2.0.2_c0961e237a04b3dab9580cd6b92b08285cdb39c3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.maps.android-android-maps-utils-0.3.4_dac5ffeda914d4aeb6f30b42d562dbab006824c8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-wearable-8.4.0_6287478ed3658867eb338478fc08f15b9de30ed5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.fedorparetsky.parcare/files/instan
```

Here is my application gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somepackage.someapplicationname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.25'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}
```

Here is my project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is the context where everything that has to do with Butterknife is happening:

```
    @BindView(R.id.input_email) AppCompatEditText _emailText;
    @BindView(R.id.input_password) AppCompatEditText _passwordText;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_login) Button _loginButton;
    @BindView(R.id.link_signup) TextView _signupLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        ...
    }
```

It looks like I followed the installation instructions for Butterknife so I'm not sure what's going on. Is there anything I need to fix?

Comment: Try Clean and then run your project. Also, Insta Run seems to be enabled, it might be that only the Activity is just restarted instead of running the whole application after a refresh install.

Comment: Yup that fixed the problem!

Comment: i am experiencing exactly same issue only on android 5.1
clean and rebuild doesnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebuilding the project compiled the entire project rather than just the single class (in Insta Run), which fixed the problem.